# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when input from user (C language)

Tags: c

Code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <string.h>

 /**
 * colour - entry point
 * @guess: input from user
 * Return: 0
 */

 void colour(char guess[100])
 {
         time_t t;
         char ans;
         int i = 3;
         char *colours[] = {"RED", "BLUE", "GREEN", "YELLOW", "BLACK"};
 
         printf("Welcome to the guessing game!!\n");
  one: printf("Do you want to play?? Enter Y/n: \n");
         scanf(" %s", &ans);
         while (ans == 'Y')
         {
                 srand((unsigned int) time(&t));
                 char *RandomColourString = colours[rand() % 5];
 
                 printf("I have 5 colours: RED, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW, BLACK.\n");
                 printf("I have chosen one of the colours, can you guess it??\n");
                 for (i = 3; i > 0; i--)
                 {
                         printf("You have %d tr%s.\n", i, i == 1 ? "y" : "ies");
                         printf("Enter your guess: \n");
                         scanf(" %99s", guess);
                         int answer = strcmp(guess, RandomColourString);
 
                         if (answer == 0)
                         {
                                 printf("You guessed it, WELL DONE!! The colour is %s.\n",
                                         RandomColourString);
                                 goto one;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                                 printf("Not the correct colour, %s.\n",
                                         i == 1 ? "game over" : "guess again");
                         }
                 }
                 printf("Sorry, you lose!! The colour is %s.\n", RandomColourString);
                 goto one;
         }
         printf("Thank you, Goodbye!!\n");
 }
```

gcc runs fine,

when I enter ./guess_colour the output is:

```
Welcome to the guessing game!!
Do you want to play?? Enter Y/n: 
Y(pressed enter after)
I have 5 colours: RED, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW, BLACK.
I have chosen one of the colours, can you guess it??
You have 3 tries.
Enter your guess: 
BLUE(pressed enter after)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How do I fix this??

I have tried vscanf and fscanf for the second scanf (scanf(" %99s", guess);) but then it doesn't run

I have also tried fgets instead of the second scanf but then it won't allow the user to input their answer for the colour choice

Comment: You have at least two `scanf` calls there. Which one is the problem (hint hint)? You don't know? I suggest cutting the code down to minimum ([mcve]), then you will find out. You can [edit] your question if you still don't know the answer.

Comment: `scanf(" %s", &ans);` this is wrong on so many levels. Please go back to your C book.

Comment: https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: There's no `main`. I don't know how you are calling this function. But `scanf(" %s", &ans);` is wrong because `ans` is not an array of `char`.

Comment: `%s` -> operates on `char` arrays, not `char` variables.

Comment: Still I wasn't able to reproduce your error. Your code ran on my machine, even though it has mistakes with arrays. That's the beauty of [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: The error is probably caused by what you are sending to the function. But we don't see it in your code.

Comment: Not the immediate cause of trouble, but it will become a cause of trouble: [`srand()` — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/15168)

Comment: Avoid `scanf`. Use `fgets` to read a line of input and then, *if needed*, `sscanf` the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
char ans;
```

and you

```
scanf(" %s", &ans);
```

When you use `%s`, you need to pass a reference to an array of characters, not a reference to a single `char`!

This operation invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: _you need to pass a reference_ -> _you need to pass a pointer_. There are no references in C.

Comment: It needs to be `" %c"` to read a single character.  Using `%s` requires an array of characters of size at least 2.  The leading blank in the format is not important (though it is harmless) with `%s`; the leading blank is usually crucial with `" %c"`.  See also [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/15168)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what did I write?

Comment: I fixed a typo "When you use `%s`m you need", replacing the 'm' with a comma.  You said that you need an array with `%s`, which is fine, but actually the OP only wants a character so it would be better/simpler to use `" %c"` than change the variable.  There's always the issue of "and what if the user types an essay instead of a single character?" — hence the reference to how to avoid a buffer overflow.  Using `" %1s"` with `char ans[2];` would work, but it is overkill compared to changing the `s` to `c`.  The fact that they added the leading space suggests the OP was thinking about `s` vs `c`.